# Bash script paths behaving differently from command-line paths

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, xdgutils

currently what I'm trying to do in Bash on my Ubuntu machine is utilize `xdg-open` to find a certain path or file.

In the command line, here's what typically happens;

When I run `xdg-open ~/Downloads/`,
This opens the file manager in the `~/Downloads/` folder, regardless of where my current directory is, as it should.

However, when I run `xdg-open ~/Downloads/` in a bash script, it attempts to read from the script's path **and** the path provided, which results in something similar to `xdg-open /path/of/my/script/~/Downloads/`, which I don't want.

My current script looks a bit like this;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter the URL or file." --title=Run --window-icon=question)

echo version=$BASH_VERSION
xdg-open "$input"

exit
```

How could I make it so my Bash script's `xdg-open` line behave how it does in the command line?

Comment: Show that part of the bash script which runs _xdg-open_. Insert into this script, right before invoking _xdg-open_, a `echo version=$BASH_VERSION` and post what you get as output.

Comment: Hard to give you an answer. The behavior you describe is not true. ~ could change expansion if HOME is redefined, but not that way. So, the real question is, why are you under the false impression it is so. Hard to tell that without seeing the script.

Comment: Hello @user1934428, After running this, the script outputs `version=5.2.2(1)-release`.

Comment: Don't put code into a comment. It's hard to read, since we don't see where a line ends. You can edit your posting by adding the necessary version.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know comments didn't support full codeblocks, I've edited my question to include the full script.

Comment: Sounds like your question is really about `zenity`, since that seems to be the program generating the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

Comment: Would work, in theory, but according to the code the OP just has added, he has no control on this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Tilde-expansion is done before parameter expansion. Hence the tilde is not expanded and `"$input"` is treated as a relative path.

You could expand your `~` manually inside the variable.

An alternative to consider would be to rewrite your shell script in zsh, where you could write `${~input}` to cause tilde expansion in parameters.

Comment: I previously tried with and without double-quotes and the result was the same, but I will keep this in mind. The closest I was able to get so far is to change directory to `~` before running `xdg-open`

Comment: Without double quote would make things even worse, because it would break on directory names containing a space. However, you are right, that I forgot that tilde expansion also does not work in unquoted parameters (I will edit my answer in this respect). In theory, `$(eval "$input")` would work, but **this** is certainly a risk you should not take.

Comment: @DabiaTheNord: BTW, you can find the expansion order for bash by checking the chapter titled _EXPANSION_ in the man page. You can see that tilde expansion is happening pretty early in the list.

Comment: as strange as it sounds, the `$(eval "$input")` is the closest I've gotten so far, however it's giving me the `/home/dabiathenord: Is a directory` message, followed by the synopsis for xdg-open.

Comment: In any case, you would certainly not do an `eval` with tainted data. Aside from this, the expansion does not look unreasonable to me. What would you have expected for your homedirectory?